# How to preserve the state of the monad stack in the IO exception handler?

Tags: haskell, exception, monads, state-monad, io-monad

Consider the following program.

```hs
import Control.Monad.State
import Control.Monad.Catch

ex1 :: StateT Int IO ()
ex1 = do
    modify (+10)
    liftIO . ioError $ userError "something went wrong"

ex2 :: StateT Int IO ()
ex2 = do
    x <- get
    liftIO $ print x

ex3 :: StateT Int IO ()
ex3 = ex1 `onException` ex2

main :: IO ()
main = evalStateT ex3 0
```

When we run the program we get the following output.

```
$ runhaskell Test.hs
0
Test.hs: user error (something went wrong)
```

However, I expected the output to be as follows.

```
$ runhaskell Test.hs
10
Test.hs: user error (something went wrong)
```

How do I preserve the intermediate state in `ex1` in the exception handler `ex2`?

Comment: Looks like you want something other than a "rollback". The only system I know which supports "non-unwinding-handle-continue" is Common Lisp.

Comment: You cannot - consider the underlying type of `StateT Int IO ()`, which is `Int -> IO Int`. If that `IO` action throws an exception, you have no access to the `Int` which it promises to produce. With a little algebra, you can see that `ex1` is simply: `\s -> let s' = s + 10 in ioError ...`. Depending on whether you really need IO or not, you might use `IORef` or the like instead of `StateT`, or you might use `ErrorT` or the like instead of `IO`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use an `IORef` (or `MVar` or `TVar` or whatever) instead.

```
newtype IOStateT s m a = IOStateT { unIOStateT :: ReaderT (IORef s) m a }
    deriving (Functor, Applicative, Monad, MonadTrans, MonadIO)
    -- N.B. not MonadReader! you want that instance to pass through,
    -- unlike ReaderT's instance, so you have to write the instance
    -- by hand

runIOStateT :: IOStateT s m a -> IORef s -> m a
runIOStateT = runReaderT . unIOStateT -- or runIOStateT = coerce if you're feeling cheeky

instance MonadIO m => MonadState s (IOStateT s m) where
    state f = IOStateT $ do
        ref <- ask
        liftIO $ do
            s <- readIORef ref
            let (a, s') = f s
            writeIORef ref s'
            pure a
```

This feels like a pattern I've seen enough times that there ought to be a Hackage package for it, but I don't know of one.